# How to convert SQL Server 2008 R2 database to SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I installed SQL Server 2012, and attached a database originally generated by SQL Server 2008 R2.

Everything appeared to work perfectly, with one problem: merges dropped from 1000 per second to 10 per second (a 100x slowdown).

I'm surmising that its because I am accessing a SQL Server 2008 R2 database from SQL Server 2012. Is there some way to convert the database to SQL Server 2012 format? Or is there something else thats going on that might explain the 100x slowdown in performance?

Comment: I should also add that my database uses horizontal partitioning, so I need something that will preserve all of the nice features of the original database.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please make sure that you set the compatibility mode of the database to 110, and update statistics.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'UPDATE STATISTICS '
  + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) 
  + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' WITH FULLSCAN;'
  FROM sys.tables;

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: you can do it in a more compact way with `EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'UPDATE STATISTICS ? WITH FULLSCAN'`

Comment: @TsahiAsher that method is not very safe, not just because that undocumented, unsupported procedure shares code with sp_MSforeachdb ([which is known to break](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)), but also because you could have multiple tables with the same name in different schemas. My code also lets you very easily add filter criteria, such as only tables with a certain naming convention or in a specific schema.

Comment: You could also run Ola Hallengren's nifty set of utilities (https://ola.hallengren.com/) to update statistics, as you should be doing this on a regular basis anyway.

Answer (score 2):

When I ran the SQL in the answer the nvarchar overflowed. The problem is when your database has too many tables the SQL is too long for an nvarchar. My database had enough tables to overflow a varchar (twice as long as a nvarchar). So I edited the SQL to loop through each table and execute separate statements. This way you wont miss updating the stats on any of your tables.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

Declare @Tables table
([Schema] nvarchar(50)
,[TableName] nvarchar(100))

Insert into @Tables
Select QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)),QUOTENAME(name) 
FROM sys.tables;

Declare @Schema nvarchar(50), @TableName nvarchar(100)

While Exists(Select * From @Tables)
Begin
    Select Top 1 @Schema = [Schema], @TableName = [TableName] From @Tables
    Set @SQL = 'UPDATE STATISTICS ' + @Schema + '.' + @TableName + ' WITH FULLSCAN;'

    Begin Try
        EXEC SP_ExecuteSql @SQLToExecute = @SQL 
        Print 'Completed: ' + @SQL
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000)
        SELECT  @ErrMsg = SubString(ERROR_MESSAGE(),0,900)

        Select GetDate(), 'Failed updating stats on ' + @Schema + ' ' + @TableName + '. Error: '+@ErrMsg
    End Catch

    Delete From @Tables Where [Schema] = @Schema and [TableName] = @TableName 
End
```

Comment: I think you are confused. How did you overflow an nvarchar(max)? Was your string really over a billion characters? Or did you assume that because PRINT showed only a portion of the command, it wasn't all there?

Comment: isn't the limit of an nvarchar(max) 4000? Or is that the param limit on SP_ExecuteSql? If so I guess just an Exec would do the job

Answer (score 1):

Updating the Stats is must when you detach and attach database. Otherwise query planner cannot generate efficient execution plan and end-up with long execution time.  This is what I noticed.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade a database file to use LocalDB:

1.In Server Explorer, choose the Connect to Database button.

2.In the Add Connection dialog box, specify the following information:

Data Source: Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)

Server Name: (LocalDB)\v11.0

Attach a database file: Path, where Path is the physical path of the primary .mdf file.

Logical Name: Name, where Name is the name that you want to use with the file.

Choose the OK button.

When prompted, choose the Yes button to upgrade the file.

Answer (score -4):

Is this on the right track:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189625.aspx

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase 
    ON (FILENAME = 'C:\MySQLServer\MyDatabase.mdf'),
    (FILENAME = 'C:\MySQLServer\Database.ldf')
    FOR ATTACH;
GO
```

Comment: I think you have already done this step, no? Why is this an answer instead of part of the question?